# Causing a stack exception (x86)

Tags: exception, x86, stack

I am trying to write assembly code to cause a stack exception but I am having no luck so far. According to the AT&T programmer manuals a stack exception is caused by one  of the following:

• Implied stack references in which the stack address is not in canonical form. Implied stack
references include all push and pop instructions, and any instruction using RSP or RBP as a base
register.
• Attempting to load a stack-segment selector that references a segment descriptor containing a clear
present bit (descriptor.P=0).
• Any stack access that fails the stack-limit check.

I went for the first method; I am trying to load rsp with a non-canonical form with the following code:

```
asm volatile("mov $0xAAAAAAAA00000000, %%rax;"
                    "orq %%rax, %%rsp;"
                    "push %%rax;" : : : );
```

GDB just says something about not being able to address memory and everything breaks rather than the exception. Does anyone have any ideas? If not does anyone know how I could cause a exception using the 3rd condition? I don't know what "fails the stack-limit check" means. Thanks!

Comment: Easiest way would probably be calling yourself over and over until you overflow the stack. See [some alternative methods that don't involve recursion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583490/without-using-recursion-how-can-a-stack-overflow-exception-be-thrown).

Answer (score 1):

```
 asm(
    "\n"
    "MYLOOP:\n\t"
    "pushq %rbp\n\t"
    //"popq %rbp\n\t"
    "jmp MYLOOP\n\t"
    );
```

Simple stack overflow.  Uncomment out the popq instruction to have an infinite stack push/pop loop consuming 100% of one cpu core.