# Can stack overflow happen without a recursive function call?

Tags: recursion, memory-management, stack-overflow

Usually when the program crashes due to stack overflow, it means there was a recursive call without a proper exit condition. But are there other ways to get the stack overflow?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583490/without-using-recursion-how-can-a-stack-overflow-exception-be-thrown

Comment: You could theoretically just have enough method calls that you stack overflow. However, this would be a sign of a terrible program design!

Answer (score 0):

If you allocate on the stack, yes, it can happen depending on the language. For example, using the C99 function `alloca`: it specifically says on the man page:

> The allocation made may exceed the bounds of the stack, or even go further into other objects in memory, and alloca() cannot determine such an error.